# Windows 8, Windows phone 8

Tags: pdf, windows-8, windows-phone-8, powerpoint

I'm looking for some nice presentations about Windows 8 and Windows Phone developing apps. Any help finding that? It can be a power point presentation, pdf, whatever. Just something for nice prelections :)

Comment: Oh people, you're so jumpy with the -1s... The guy's asking for documentation, it's not that hard to point him some...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly, you can find a lot on **MSDN**, both for Windows Phone and for Windows 8. Now, it mostly depends on your current level and direction in using programming languages, because, for developing apps for Windows 8, you could use :

- C++
- Visual Basic
- C# and XAML
- JavaScript and HTML

If you're the type of learning from PDFs, I'd recommend you Charles Petzold's books :

- Programming Windows 6th Edition, Microsoft Press (for Windows 8 app development using C# and XAML)
- Programming Windows Phone 7, Microsoft Press (I know, I know, you might have wanted the Windows Phone 8, but mostly the things are the same or very similar, it's OK at least for a start)

If you're looking for online video tutorials, **Channel9** can provide you great ones :

- [Windows Phone 8 for absolute beginners](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners)
- [Windows Phone code samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/)

As for Windows 8, the things are getting tricky, Depends if you wish 8 or 8.1, so I'll provide links for both :

- [Windows 8.1 Code Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples)
- [Windows 8 Code Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/)

Personally, for now I still stick to Windows 8, altough the update is going to be free, I bet there are gonna be lots of lazy people who won't update (Windows 8.1 apps won'r run on Windows 8 unless it gets updated)

Have fun!